# Knockout.js - Data binding outputting function text when not using parens

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am new to Knockout and have been trying to follow code examples and the documentation, but keep running into an issue. My data bindings printing the Knockout observable function, not the actual values held by my observable fields. I can get the value if I evaluate the field using (), but if you do this you do not get any live data-binding / updates.

Below are some code snippets from my project that are directly related to the issue I am describing:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
   <div data-bind="foreach: leftColSocialAPIs">
      <div class="social-metric">
         <img data-bind="attr: { src: iconPath }" /> 
         <strong data-bind="text: name"></strong>:
         <span data-bind="text: totalCount"></span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Note: leftColSocialAPIs contains an array of SocialAPIs. I can show that code too if needed.

**Initializing the totalcount attribute**

```
var SocialAPI = (function (_super) {
__extends(SocialAPI, _super);
function SocialAPI(json) {
    _super.call(this, json);
    this.totalCount = ko.observable(0);
    this.templateName = "social-template";
}
SocialAPI.prototype.querySuccess = function () {
    this.isLoaded(true);
    appManager.increaseBadgeCount(this.totalCount());
    ga('send', 'event', 'API Load', 'API Load - ' + this.name, appManager.getRedactedURL());
};
SocialAPI.prototype.toJSON = function () {
    var self = this;
    return {
        name: self.name,
        isActive: self.isActive(),
        type: "social"
    };
};
return SocialAPI;
})(API);
```

**Updating totalcount attribute for LinkedIn**

```
var LinkedIn = (function (_super) {
__extends(LinkedIn, _super);
function LinkedIn(json) {
    json.name = "LinkedIn";
    json.iconPath = "/images/icons/linkedin-16x16.png";
    _super.call(this, json);
}
LinkedIn.prototype.queryData = function () {
    this.isLoaded(false);
    this.totalCount(0);
    $.get("http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share", { "url": appManager.getURL(), "format": "json" }, this.queryCallback.bind(this), "json").fail(this.queryFail.bind(this));
};
LinkedIn.prototype.queryCallback = function (results) {
    if (results != undefined) {
        results.count = parseInt(results.count);
        this.totalCount(isNaN(results.count) ? 0 : results.count);
    }
    this.querySuccess();
};
return LinkedIn;
})(SocialAPI);
```

In the `<span data-bind="text: totalCount"></span>`, I expect to see a number ranging from 0-Integer.MAX. Instead I see the following:

[image: outputting function]
As you can see, its outputting the knockout function itself, not the value of the function. Every code example I've seen, including those in the official documentation, says that I should be seeing the value, not the function. What am I doing wrong here? I can provide the full application code if needed.

Comment: yeah i would create a plunker or reveal all your code

Comment: If you evaluate the field using () you will still get live bindings, but it shouldn't be required in this case. You need to evaluate it if you were doing something like <span data-bind="text: 'count: ' + totalCount()"></span>. Without a jsfiddle it's too hard to work out what's wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but KO view models obviously tend to bind *own* (not inherited through prototypes) observable properties only. So you should rewrite your code to supply `totalCount` observable for every social network separately.